# calling maps.app (Apple maps) with navigation using latitude and longitude

Tags: objective-c, apple-maps

I want to call the maps application from my app, and sent it a url with latitude and longitude on source address and destination address (for navigation)

How do I construct the link?

Answer (score 2):

You should create an instance of `MKMapItem` and use the `openMapsWithItems:launchOptions:` method to open the maps app.

Check [this reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html).

---

For iOS 5 (which you should think about dropping support for) I think the format was:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",
                currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude,
                destinationLocation.latitude, destinationLocation.longitude];
```

Comment: Thats nice solution for iOS6 , but I need to support iOS5